# Printing the characters obtained from the array s using printf?

Tags: c

Explain the below problem:

```
main() {
  static char s[25]="vector"; int i=0;
  char ch;
  ch=s[++i];
  printf("%c", ch);
  ch=s[i++];
  printf("%c", ch);
  ch=i++[s];
  printf("%c", ch);
  ch=++i[s];
  printf("%c", ch);
}
```

OUTPUT :: eecu

I'm trying to figure out how the word 'eec' came to be, but I'm having some trouble.  Would you mind sharing your thoughts on this with me?

Comment: You give as output "eecu" but you ask about "eec". Can you clarify what looks like an inconsistence? I seem to have no problems with explaining "eec", but the "u" distracts me considerably. Can you state the output you expect? Or otherwise narrow down which part of "eec" surprises you?

Comment: Can  you upgrade the shown code to a [mre]? Maybe focus it on the part of output which surprises you? Maybe double check the last `ch=++i[s];` because I have an idea how the "u" could come from a different but similar line.

Comment: @Prabhu The ‘u’ comes from the line `ch=++i[s];`. C evaluates the expression `array[index]` as `*(array + index)`. Since the arithmetic is commutative, `index[array]` is evaluated as `*(index + array)`. This allows bizarre expressions like `++i[s];`, which is evaluated as `++*(i + s)`. Since `i` becomes 3 at this line, `s[3]` is incremented and ‘t’ becomes ‘u’. Better to write `ch=++s[i];`.